# Is there any point using CI encryption to encrypt stored data

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

So I'm hoping this is not too discursive a question - but I am looking at encryption and the CodeIgniter encryption library. Great. But I'm just wondering in the following circumstance if there is actually any point encrypting my data?

1. No open port access to MySQL (all done via key based SSH)
2. Key stored in CI config file (which resides on the same box)
3. Server is a Ubuntu Linode (Cloud server)
4. I am the only person with access to the box

Why should I store my data at rest? Wikipedia mentions "unauthorised access or theft" but that would require physically stealing the box which is unlikely. I guess access to my machine if I'm logged into a database and the data is unreadable but again - unless someone breaks into my house and unlocks my machine its highly unlikely.

Comment: Will you not make offsite database backups? How will they get offsite? If anyone ever gets ahold of one of those backups and the data is not encrypted, that's on you.

Comment: Backups are handled by the hosting company (and are held in the same datacentre). But because its cloud its fully backed up so would include the key in the config files and potentially (I don't know how the backups work) hold the key in memory if that is copied too. So doesn't that negate the point?

Comment: It sort of depends on the data. It's super simple to encrypt and decrypt, and if I'm storing people's personal information on my server, it's going to be encrypted. Should something happen, I want to prove that I did my best to secure that data, and not encrypting is not doing my best. If you get hacked or something, how will you explain that you didn't secure the data the best way possible? More importantly, how will your attorney do that for you in court when somebody is suing you? If you're storing driver's license numbers, SSNs, etc. you should encrypt. Evil people want that data.

Comment: Another thing to think about. If you're so confident that you are secure, would you store plain text passwords in your database? Look at the big companies that have been hacked. It happens.

Comment: This question sounds perfectly on topic for security.stackexchange.com. For this site, it's a bit out of scope.

Comment: Good point - is someone able to move it for me?